# Clang-format don't break long line with comment before dot

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm using `clang-format` to autoformat code in a **C++-*like dialect***, which **does not support line breaks before dots in chained commands or declarations**.

#### Input

F.i. **the following is ok** for our dialect but of course exceeds the `ColumnLimit: 80` definition in the `.clang-format` style file (please mind the long comment **without any spaces** (except for the leading space)):

```
extern int some_outer_scope.some_variable;  // Description.where.this.variable.is.coming.from.which.is.far.too.long.and.should.be.broken
```

#### Current faulty output

which clang-format (settings see below) formats to the following style **which is not supported by our dialect** (breaking before chained commands or scope resolutions operators etc. is not supported):

```
extern int some_outer_scope
  .some_variable;  // Description.where.this.variable.is.coming.from.which.is.far.too.long.and.should.be.broken
```

#### Expected outputs:

Any of the following outputs would be ok:

1. Leave it as it is **ignoring the `ColumnLimit` in this specific case**, f.i. by somehow declaring specific keywords such as `extern` to be skipped by clang-format (didn't find such an option)

   ```
   extern int some_outer_scope.some_variable;  // Description.where.this.variable.is.coming.from.which.is.far.too.long.and.should.be.broken
   ```
2. **Preferably** break comment at one of the following delimiters: `::`, `.` **or** just break the comment **anywhere** to satisfy the `ColumnLimit`:

   ```
   extern int some_outer_scope.some_variable;  // Description.where.this.variable
                                               // .is.coming.from.which.is.far.too.long.and
                                               // .should.be.broken
   // Or
   extern int some_outer_scope.some_variable;  // Description.where.this.variable.is.coming.fr
                                               // om.which.is.far.too.long.and.should.be.broken
   ```

#### Clang-format style config

```yaml
---
BasedOnStyle: Google
IndentWidth: 2
---
Language: Cpp
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent
AlignArrayOfStructures: Right
AlignConsecutiveAssignments:
  Enabled: true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCompound: true
  PadOperators: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations:
  Enabled: true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
AlignConsecutiveMacros:
  Enabled: false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
AlignOperands: Align
AlignTrailingComments:
  Kind: Never
  OverEmptyLines: 0
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: false
  AfterControlStatement: Never
  AfterFunction: false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeElse: true
  BeforeWhile: false
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
#BreakAdjacentStringLiterals: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: NonAssignment
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit: 80
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 2
ContinuationIndentWidth: 2
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
IncludeBlocks: Merge
IndentExternBlock: AfterExternBlock
IndentPPDirectives: BeforeHash
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
InsertBraces: false
InsertNewlineAtEOF: true
InsertTrailingCommas: None
KeepEmptyLinesAtEOF: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
LineEnding: LF
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 0
PenaltyBreakComment: 0
PenaltyBreakString: 0
PPIndentWidth: -1
ReflowComments: true
RemoveSemicolon: true
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Always
SortIncludes: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2
SpacesInAngles: Never
SpacesInConditionalStatement: true
SpacesInLineCommentPrefix:
  Minimum: 1
  Maximum: 1
SpacesInParentheses: true
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard: Latest
TabWidth: 2
TypeNames: ['int', 'string']
UseTab: Never
...
```

Comment: Does the problem go away if you change `ColumnLimit: 80` to `ColumnLimit: 509`?

Comment: Yes, but changing the column limit is not an option. 80 characters maximum is required.

Comment: Your example has a line that is 136 characters long, which exceeds your stated 80 characters maximum requirement.

Comment: I know, this is why I want to break the line at the comment - if possible. Unluckily breaking the code at the `.` is not supported by our dialect. I added some more information to my question, thanks for the remark.

Comment: I recommend using the online [clang-format configurator](https://clang-format-configurator.site/), and twiddle the settings until you get something that is acceptable.

Comment: I already tried exactly this configurator with all kinds of options, even adding `extern` to the special lists such as macros. But I didn't find any useful option. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256614/discussion-between-eljay-and-je-muc).